# Find the missing number

Tags: logic, self-learning

> Find the missing numbers in the bottom middle circle. (Clue: left halves of the
>   central circles relate to the left circles and the right halves to the right circles)

circles are attached in the image

[image: Circles]

I am not able to find the numbers with the clue also. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps. This might be giving more than a 'hint' but still.

[image]

Sorry for the messiness.

Comment: That's indeed a good bit more than a hint ...

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Ans is 6,2. Am I correct?

Comment: @RDE Yes, 6 and 2. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Think multiplication and division

Comment: I do not get it yet. Please give me some more hint.

Comment: @RDE Multiplication on the left ...

Answer (score -1):

My answer is $6,2$
By using clue we are multiply by the left circles ( like $1\cdot 2$ and $3\cdot 4$ and $5\cdot 6$ we get left central circles values $2$ and $12$ and $30$ respectively)... similar way we use bottom of the left half central circles....then we get the value $6$
Similarly , we divide by the right circles values (like $4÷1$ and $6÷3$ and $9÷3$ we get right half central circles values $4$ and $3$ and $3$ respectively) similarly way we use bottom of the right half of the central circles value is $2$

Comment: Your numbers look like they are not formatted correctly. In particular using `*` to denote multiplication is an issue on this site because `*italics*` becomes *italics*. You can see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference on how to format mathematics with Mathjax (I didn't read the question or your answer)